# Creating Templates for new .h and .cpp files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for C++ coding. I like to have my header files and cpp files all nicely organized with comment blocks etc and I was wondering if there was someway to automate this process through a template?

When i click add item, i'm given a list of items to add which include a blank .h file and .cpp file but I'd love to be able to customize that to add the ClassName at the top, the ifndef,define block etc.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247069(v=VS.100).aspx) is a link to appropriate MSDN page.

Comment: File + Export Template is going to take a couple of versions in the C++ IDE.  It is still way too married to the custom wizards from 14 years ago. You might make @Yahia's answer work by editing hfile.h and newc++file.cpp

Comment: Thanks Hans, I took Yahia's advice and got more or less the functionality I wanted.

Comment: Approach described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx does not work - described the issue in Community Content at that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure whether this is what you are looking for but check this out

The default templates are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcprojectitems. Change as appropriate for x86-vs-x64 and VS version.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously not able to replace words with the classname, but simple copy paste works well enough and I have a consistent template to use on all of my classes now. Much appreciated!